# Python: Read list of dataframe from csv file

Tags: python, list, dataframe, csv

I export a list of dataframes to a csv file using .to_csv(), when I try to read data back, it merges all dataframes and return only one dataframe.

mydata:

```
[                  v1        v2
 time                        
 
 2019-08-04  7.308368  4.622069
 2019-08-05  6.318558  3.993616
 ...              ...       ...
 2020-07-31  3.397716  1.914453
 2020-08-01  2.232000  1.534888
 
 [364 rows x 2 columns],
                   v1        v2
 time                        
 
 2019-08-04  0.400307  0.322742
 2019-08-05  0.306128  0.229573
 ...              ...       ...
 2020-07-28  0.405865  0.335051
 2020-08-01  0.508580  0.394044
 
 [367 rows x 2 columns],
                   v1        v2
 time                        
 2019-08-01  4.892139  3.420369
 2019-08-05  4.375880  3.181351
 ...              ...       ...
 2019-12-05       NaN       NaN
 2019-12-09  1.078299  0.590751
 
 [131 rows x 2 columns],
..]
```

csv file:

```
time;v1;v2
2019-08-01;5.004642491294296;2.070262692905746
2019-08-02;6.005581617403156;3.5806659894959636
2019-08-03;5.720055440019435;4.076401038795619
...
time;v1;v2
2019-08-04;7.308368263370739;4.6220686806106
2019-08-05;6.318558302126913;3.9936164101171587
2019-08-06;5.602923231110271;3.455379392672936
...
time;v1;v2
2019-08-07;4.12752721072869;2.4488549880224264
2019-08-08;5.244169560874248;3.150645259745313
...
```

reading csv file:

```
data= pd.read_csv('results.csv', delimiter = ";", index_col=0, header = 0)
```

data:

```
                v1                    v2
time        
2019-08-01  5.004642491294296   2.070262692905746
2019-08-05  6.318558302126913   3.9936164101171587
...     ...     ...
2020-07-28  18.93710638512659   15.27918513484749
2020-08-01  45.634680485520484  33.58384984534077

**1858 rows × 2 columns**
```

How can I return dataframes seperatly in a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Save** it as pickle, to keep the list datatype:

```
import pickle as pkl
df_list = [] # all your dataframes in a list
pkl.dump(df_list, open("your_pkl_file.pkl","wb"))
```

**To load it** again:

```
df_list = pkl.load(open("your_pkl_file.pkl", "rb"))
for i in df_list:
    #do operations with your dataframes here
```

I think that is much easier than saving it as csv, except for you absolutely need to store it as csv. Then you have to save each df independently, for having a clean working environment in different files.